# How to handle text file with multiple spaces as delimiter

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a source data set which consists of text files where the columns are separated by one or more spaces, depending on the width of the column value. The data is right adjusted, i.e. the spaces are added before the actual data.

Can I use one of the built-in extractors or do I have to implement a custom extractor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom extractor or more simply, import the data as one row then split and clean and it using c# methods available to you within U-SQL like `Split` and `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, something like this:

[My right-aligned sample data](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e9706432640d8d9458ddadf5f780dd82)

```
// Import the row as one column to be split later; NB use a delimiter that will NOT be in the import file
@input =
    EXTRACT rawString string
    FROM "/input/input.txt"
    USING Extractors.Text(delimiter : '|');


// Add a row number to the line and remove white space elements
@working =
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS rn, new SqlArray<string>(rawString.Split(' ').Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))) AS columns
    FROM @input;


// Prepare the output, referencing the column's position in the array
@output =
    SELECT rn,
           columns[0] AS id,
           columns[1] AS firstName,
           columns[2] AS lastName
    FROM @working;


OUTPUT @output
TO "/output/output.txt"
USING Outputters.Tsv(quoting : false);
```

My results:

[image: My Results]
HTH

Answer (score 1):

@wBob's solution works if your row fits into a string (128kB). Otherwise, write your custom extractor that does fixed with extraction. Depending on what information you have on the format, you can write it by using `input.Split()` to split into rows and then split the rows based on your whitespace rules as shown below (full example for Extractor pattern is [here](https://github.com/Azure/usql/blob/master/Examples/AmbulanceDemos/AmbulanceDemoCode/Class1.cs)) or you could write one similar to the one described in [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/data_otaku/2016/10/27/a-fixed-width-extractor-for-azure-data-lake-analytics/).

```
    public override IEnumerable<IRow> Extract(IUnstructuredReader input, IUpdatableRow outputrow) 
     { 
         foreach (Stream current in input.Split(this._row_delim)) 
         { 
             using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(current, this._encoding)) 
             { 
                 int num = 0; 
                 string[] array = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[]{this._col_delim}, StringSplitOptions.None).Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))); 
                 for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) 
                 { 
                     // Now write your code to convert array[i] into the extract schema
                 } 
             } 
             yield return outputrow.AsReadOnly(); 
         } 
     } 
 }
```

Comment: Great addition, and important point about the 128KB limit, thanks @MichaelRys.